# Grep regex for string "company" and replace "company old"

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep

I need to search for a string "company" but this string repeats in different ways.

ex: "company" changed the name but did not change it completely just added a new name. So what I need to do now is, find company and change to company old.

now I need to find the company name every where, to change the name I need to void to find  **company old** because in some case it is already there.

I have done grep -rl "company" but brings me all of it.

Comment: Providing an exact input and desired output would be great.

Comment: Does your expected `company` has a special attribute?

Comment: You may want to take a look at `pcregrep` which support perl-like lookahead patters like `company(?! old)` (match "company" if it is not followed by " old").  But yeah, what exactly is the specification of your problem?

Comment: @CongMa no need for pcre grep, `grep -oP 'company(?!\s+old\b)'`

Comment: ok,, if do  **"grep -oP 'company(?!\s+old\b)'"**  will only look for **company ** not for ** company old**, right?

Comment: It's very unclear what you want. Your subject says you want to find `company` and replace `company old` but doesn't say what you want to replace it with and then your question sounds like you really want to just exclude `company old` from the results of your search for `company` and then you don't say what you want printed if `company` is found. It's kindof a mess. Edit your question to show some clear sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform a substitution, maybe something like

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { %h=("company old" => "company old", "company" => "Whizzbang, Inc.") }
    s/(company old|company)/$h{$1}/g'
```

This will bypass "company old" occurrences by replacing them with themselves, then replace any other matches with the new string.

Comment: thanks, I will try that as well, if does not work, I can roll back

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is print each line that contains `company` but not `company old` then all you need is:

```
awk '/company/ && !/company old/' file
```

If instead you want to replace all instances of `company` that aren't part of `company old`:

```
$ cat file
foo company old bar company indeed
$ awk '{gsub(/company old/,RS); gsub(/company/,"Acme Corp"); gsub(RS,"company old")}1' file
foo company old bar Acme Corp indeed
```

If it's something else, edit your question to clarify with an example.